# HTML/Razor setting up class for div via variable results in wrong class

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC view razor page I have this code:

```
@if (TempData["notice"] != null)
{
  var clss = string.Concat("alert ", (TempData["noticeClass"]).ToString(), " alert-dismissible");
  <div class=@clss role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h3>@TempData["notice"]</h3>
  </div>
}
```

The idea is that I can set the color of the bootstrap alert in the controller together with the message.
For example TempData["NoticeClass"] is set to "alert-success".

If I put a break on the line with 'var clss =' then I can see that the clss variable is build correctly.
It shows:

> "alert alert-success alert-dismissible"

But when I run the page and inspect it I get to see this:

```
<div class="alert" alert-success="" alert-dismissible="" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
<h3>The email address 'blabla@bla.com' has been updated.</h3>
```

As you can see the class for the div is set only to the first part.
Did I just find a bug in Visual Studio 2015 or is this intended and I am doing something wrong??

Comment: No offense, but always assume you did something wrong. The likelihood that you are the first to notice a bug affecting something like this, is like a quadrillion to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`<div class="@clss" role="alert">`

Even though its a string value, you still need to include the quotes.

Comment: Good catch. Yet another reason you should always include the quotes around attributes, even though they aren't explicitly required.

Comment: Timing is everything.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson: First, Ian was the first to answer, if only just barely. Second, it's not uncommon for people to both be writing basically the same answer at the same time and post it without realizing someone else already posted it.

Comment: Thanks!  this is the first time I use a variable, one I created, use. So learned something new today :-)

Comment: No problem. Glad to see that you're trying to push your limits!

Comment: @ChrisPratt Alright. On my screen it said Ian was a full minute later. I thought maybe he had just copied Cosmin's answer

Comment: It says Ian answer one more minute "ago" than Cosmin. That means temporally he was first, not second. It's a moot point, though. Generally, if the time frame between answers is 5 minutes are less, you can safely assumed they answered simultaneously. If it was like hours later, then I'd question it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<div class="@clss" role="alert">
```